# How to make dropdown choices that change text or paragraph below the dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, web, css-transitions

Ive been searching all day over the internet but I cant find solution to my problem, and my problem is maybe simple for you guys but as a newbie, I cant really explain it clearly. Here it is, I want to create a choices from dropdown list, when a user picks from the choices, there is a text line that shows or changes everytime a user change its choice in dropdown.

• Option 1 
• Option 2
• Option 3
Any type of text

**If user picks the option 1, there is a designated text to be shown below, if user picks option 2 in dropdown, the text below will change to designated for option 2 then option 3 is the same. I hope you get my point guys. Thanks so much for helps.

Comment: Please read this. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what have to tried so far???

Answer (score 0):

Add a function to `onchange` of select and pass the value of the selected option

```js
function showPara(val) {
  // check if the value is not empty or undefined
  if (val !== undefined && val !== "") {
    // then selelct all the p element which have a common class and add the coass which hide the element
    document.querySelectorAll(".pClass").forEach(function(item) {
      item.classList.add("hidePara");
      // remove the class hide element where the id of p matches with the selected value
      document.getElementById(val).classList.remove('hidePara')
    })
  }
}
```

```css
.hidePara {
  display: none;
}

.pClass {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<select onchange="showPara(this.value)">
<option>Select</option>
<option value ='1'>Option 1</option>
<option value ='2'>Option 2</option>
<option value ='3'>Option 3</option>
<option value ='4'>Option 4</option>
</select>

<p id="1" class="pClass hidePara">Para 1</p>
<p id="2" class="pClass hidePara">Para 2</p>
<p id="3" class="pClass hidePara">Para 3</p>
<p id="4" class="pClass hidePara">Para 4</p>
```